# No template found for SomeController#create rendering head :no_content

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am building a rails app that creates a like(create) or unlike(destroy), on a link click with a remote: true ajax request

The Post goes through and the transaction is committed but the the js response is not going through and I receive a Error in the server console

```
No template found for ForumThreads::ForumPosts::LikesController#create, head :no_content
```

the view structure is

```
forum_threds/show.html.haml
....
  = render @forum_thread.forum_posts
....
```

to render a view of every post that is in the thread
than

```
forum_posts/_forum_post.html.haml
....
  %div{id: "fourm_post_#{forum_post.id}" }
  = render partial: "forum_posts/likes", locals: { post: forum_post }
....
```

which is rendering

```
forum_posts/_likes.html.haml
- if user_signed_in? && current_user.likes?(post)
  = link_to "UnLike", forum_post_likes_path(post), method: :delete, 
    remote: true
- else
  = link_to "Like", forum_post_likes_path(post), method: :post, remote: 
    true
```

and my controller is

```
class ForumThreads::ForumPosts::LikesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_forum_post
  before_action :set_forum_thread

  def create
    @forum_post.likes.where(user_id: current_user.id).first_or_create

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html { redirect_to @forum_thread}
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @forum_post.likes.where(user_id: current_user.id).destroy_all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html { redirect_to @forum_thread}
    end
  end

  private

  def set_forum_thread
    @forum_thread = ForumThread.find(@forum_post.forum_thread_id)
  end

  def set_forum_post
    @forum_post = ForumPost.find(params[:forum_post_id])
  end
end
```

With remote: false this works as expected with the page reload but when i put remote: true I receive the no template error

my file structure for the views

- forum_threads/

  - show.html.haml
  - forum_posts/

    - show.html.haml
    - _likes.html.haml
    - likes/

      - create.js.erb
      - destroy.js.erb

and the create.js.erb and destroy.js.erb

```
$("#forum_post_<%= forum_post.id %>").html(<%= j render 
  'forum_posts/likes' %>);
```

but i know that this file isn't even being called

is there a way from the format.js that i may be able to call the file i need directly? or something?

Comment: I am not great with JS but in your js view, there is an error. You use `forum_post.id` instead of `@forum_post.id`. otherwise in your `format.js` you can explicitly pass a view to render. This is in case your structure is unusual and the default `create.js.erb` is not automatically found.

Comment: What does your console show when you click the link? It should say something like `Processing by LikesController#create as JS`

Comment: How can I define the location?

Comment: No template found for ForumThreads::ForumPosts::LikesController#create, head :no_content . is what the console shows, everything else is normal

Comment: I was able to get most of the way through the problem by passing format.js { render 'path/to/file' } now my pages js isn't updating but i see the correct retun in the dev console

Comment: @CoreyGibson What do you mean by "normal"? Your question is more clear if you can "demonstrate" that it's normal, rather than telling us on faith. Do your controllers do anything unusual with [`append_view_path`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/append_view_path/class)? What is the value of [`view_paths`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/view_paths) in that controller?